# Restore job "stuck"

Tags: sql-server, restore

After a restore job I can't read from database until I kill that long-running job. 
I'll try to give as much info as I can but being that I'm stuck I'm not sure what is pertinent.

- We are using RedGate's SQL Backup to restore log-shipping incrementals, this runs on a Sql Sever job hourly. Files come from a vendor, and that is how they send us data.
- Database is always in Read-Only/Standby mode.
- Command we run is:

```
SET @cmd = CONCAT('-SQL "RESTORE LOG [DB] FROM DISK = ''', @SourceFolder, '\LOG*.SQB'' WITH  MOVETO=''', @SourceFolder, '\temp\'', STANDBY = ''D:\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\db.dat'', CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR, DISCONNECT_EXISTING,PASSWORD = ''', @Password,'''')
EXECUTE [master]..sqlbackup @cmd, @errorcode OUT, @sqlerrorcode OUT;
```

- Job just times out and moves on even though it is set to fail on error - but that is not my question now.
- Database is still in Read-Only/Standby mode, but any read times out.
- Running sp_whoisactive returns:

```
+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| dd hh:mm:ss.mss |                                                                                                   sql_text                                                                                                   |     login_name      |                wait_info                 |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| 00 07:55:45.250 | <?query --sqlbackup--?>                                                                                                                                                                                      | _Service            | (28543510ms)PREEMPTIVE_OS_GETPROCADDRESS |
| 00 07:55:40.973 | <?query --RESTORE LOG [DB]  FROM VIRTUAL_DEVICE = 'SQLBACKUP_4E37B8AF-7BCF-492F-91BC-AA1697A7B473' WITH BUFFERCOUNT = 6, BLOCKSIZE = 65536, MAXTRANSFERSIZE = 1048576 , NORECOVERY, CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR--?> | NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM | (28538667ms)BACKUPIO                     |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

- In the RedGate log I see:  Warning 445: Get exclusive local data store access failed - timeout.
- In the Event viewer I see a bunch of: SQLVDI: Loc=TriggerAbort. Desc=invoked. ErrorCode=(0). Process=3024. Thread=6560. Server. Instance=MSSQLSERVER. VD=Global\SQLBACKUP_3F946102-4D96-43A1-9596-29358E1589AA_SQLVDIMemoryName_0.

Comment: Why not contact Redgate support? They're quite responsive in my experience.

Comment: @LowlyDBA thanks, some reason I thought that you need to be a licensed user for that (my manager is, but not me.) but that is not true anybody can join and ask.